# How to get the actual type of primitive type parameter in Scala Seq[T] or Option[T]?

Tags: java, scala, reflection

For example if I have a `class NewClass(val a: Seq[String])`, I'm able to get the actual type of the type parameter by `classOf[NewClass].getDeclaredFields.head.getGenericType.asInstanceOf[java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType].getActualTypeArguments.head.asInstanceOf[Class[_]]` which is a `java.lang.String`.

However, if the type parameter is a primitive type (which is not allowed in Java, but allowed in Scala), such as `class NewClass(val a: Seq[Int])`, using the same approach would only yield `java.lang.Object`. Is there any way for me to know that it's actually an `Int` instead of the general `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: Manifest is the simplest solution, but you've indicated the code is generated and won't work. May I ask WHY you need the type? Can you post some context? Perhaps there's another solution.

Comment: I'm trying to create a web based thrift client for the our thrift service which implements the interface generated by Scrooge.  Now seems like the best solution right now is to modify Scrooge to generate Manifest in some form.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the manifest?

```
scala> class NewClass[T](val a: Seq[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T])
defined class NewClass

scala> class NewClass[T](val a: Seq[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
     |   def typeOfA = m.erasure
     | }
defined class NewClass

scala> val newClass = new NewClass(Seq(1, 2, 3))
newClass: NewClass[Int] = NewClass@494e1df7

scala> newClass.typeOfA
res17: java.lang.Class[_] = int
```

Comment: I know this works.  But unfortunately I'm using Scrooge-generated Scala code from thrift, which doesn't use Manifest...

Answer (score 0):

If you define a version like below it will work for all classes that have one type parameter.

```
scala> def f[F[_],A](a: F[A])(implicit m:Manifest[A]) = m.erasure
f: [F[_], A](a: F[A])(implicit m: Manifest[A])java.lang.Class[_]

scala> f(Option(1))
res4: java.lang.Class[_] = int

scala> f(List(1,2,3))
res5: java.lang.Class[_] = int

scala> f(new NewClass(Seq(1, 2, 3)))
res6: java.lang.Class[_] = int

scala> f(new NewClass(Seq(1, 2, 3)).a)
res8: java.lang.Class[_] = int
```